# Can I know the range of each eigenvalue when I know sum and product of the eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I obtained two eigenvalues from matrix, $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.

Since sum of two eigenvalues is trace of matrix and product is determinant, I know that $\lambda_1$+ $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_1 \lambda_2 >1$.

In this case, can I know whether each $\lambda_i$ is less than 1 or not?

Comment: Are we talking about $2\times2$ matrices? If so, this information should be in the question (and if not, the question is nonsense).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw *some* conclusions about the two eigenvalues, but nothing particularly conclusive.

On the individual level, describing one eigenvalue, you can conclude that it is positive. This is because if one eigenvalue would be negative, then $\lambda_1\lambda_2>1>0$ means that the other eigenvalue should also be negative, but that contradicts the inequality $\lambda_1+\lambda_2 > 1> 0$.

That, however, is *all* you can say about an individual eigenvalue. Each positive value $x>0$ could potentially be an eigenvalue, so long as the other eigenvalue is greater than $\max(1, \frac1x)$.

You can also not conclude that either of the eigenvalues is bounded above by any value, since for any $M>0$, you can have $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=M+1$ and both inequalities will still be satisfied.